# Azure Runbook - Create from gallery using a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I was trying to create a RunBook in Azure Automation and I chose to use a  Powershell script (Cmdlet). But the creation failed with an error because azure couldn't directly convert it and a manual edit is required to make it a "workflow". I am not a pro on PS and I understand you need to know how a workflow works. But my immediate goal is to get the Runbook working and hence trying to figure out an easy way to convert a PS script to a PS workflow for the purpose of runbook... Appreciate any help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this blog post for info on PowerShell script to PowerShell Workflow conversion: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/25/introducing-the-azure-automation-script-converter/

However, regardless of conversion, you can't interact with local files on your computer from Azure Automation, so this script won't work. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03a7aace-4e3e-4dab-9a8f-4ed1002fde4e/how-to-upload-files-from-users-machine-to-blob-storage-using-azure-automation?forum=azureautomation for more details.